# Facebook messenger bot: How embed a video after button click?

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

`Hello and thanks,

I would like to embed a small video inside FB Messenger after a button is clicked.

Code below.
First button below opens in a browser
2nd fails
3rd works.

I've done it Manychat so it can be done.
I've spent hours on what seems like a simple thing.

```
        "title": "More Information",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "web_url",
            "url": "https://youtu.be/E9E4cEj3n80?t=7s",
            "title": "Video Explanation"
          },
          {
            "type": "video",
            "payload": {
              "url": "http://gwe.net/idiom_images/cat_bag.mp4"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "element_share"
          }
        ]
      }
```

`

Comment: Hi Jim! Did you manage to solve this problem?